# How to print in the console that figure?

Tags: eclipse

I want to print that in the console:

```
*
**
***
**
*
```

so, my code is:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = input.nextInt();

        char c = '*';
        if (1 < n && n < 20) {
            for (int row = 1; row <= n; row++) {
                for (int col = 1; col <= row; col++) {

                        System.out.print(c);
                    }
                    System.out.println();

                }
```

any proposals how to finish?

Comment: What is your expect out put? or Update the out put pattern(figure).

Comment: what value has n? Why do you write your code that difficult?

Answer (score 0):

You want to print "* **". Write this:

```
System.out.print("* **");
```

If my answer is not that what you excpected, than give us more information. What is your actual problem. See [StackOverflowFAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: sorry, my question was wrong- the size of the figure is the n( what you input in the console, int n = input.nextInt(); here is n =3,tks

Answer (score 0):

If `n` is your `"*"` length,below code:

```
if (1 < n && n < 20) {
            for (int row = 1; row <= n; row++) {
                for (int col = 1; col <= row; col++) {

                    System.out.print(c);
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            for (int row =1; row <= n; row++) {
                for (int col = n-row; col >0 ; col--) {

                    System.out.print(c);
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Or If n is your "*" length,below code- that one works. tks a lot!